# Laravel no me permite hacer migraciones

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo 2 tablas en Laravel.
La primera es User, con estas caracteristicas:

```
Schema::create('users',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Y por otro lado una tabla llamada Mensaje, con estas propiedades:

```
Schema::create('mensajes',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('mensaje');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

La idea es enviar un email a un usuario, y tras eso, crear una copia del mensaje en la tabla Mensaje.
Tras crear mis tablas, uso `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` para hacer las migraciones, pero me sale esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que significara este mensaje de error?

Comment: Cambia esta línea $table->unsignedInteger('user_id') por $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')

Comment: Yo he usado "increments" en las variables "id" para solucionarlo. Parece que las ultimas actualizaciones ha trastocado las cosas un poco.

Comment: El mensaje significa que la tabla ya existe... prueba con `php artisan migrate:fresh`